# Color Coding Shades of Hex Colors Criteria

Tags: android, colors, android-jetpack-compose

I am following this Jetpack Compose [Codelab on Theming](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#3) and I'm trying to grasp the logic used to name these shades of the **Red Color** but I am lost.

[image]

Here the ***Red700*** is `#DD0D3C` but when I check with the [Material Design Palette](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=D32F2F), ***Red700*** corresponds to `#D32F2F`

[image]

When I Google the Hex Value for ***Red700*** I am getting mixed results on the value. What I know is that the shades represent a different percentage of the Red Color but can't understand the logic in naming the shades.

Therefore my question is what is the criteria for naming shades of a color. I would also be interested to know if there is a tool online to generate uniformly named shades of a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a handle on this one.

The simple answer is that there is no uniform values for Shades of a color. From one color you can generate ten, twenty or more shades and it is up you to rename the shades depending on your scale.

In the process I learnt that a Color Shade is a hue or mixture of pure colors to which only black is added. It contains no white or gray. Shade darkens the color.

I also discovered this awesome [Online Tool for Generating Color Shades](https://mdigi.tools/color-shades/#ff0000).